# Ifelse generating numeric values in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't quite find the answer I'm looking for. I'm trying to match some characters across two columns in a dataframe:

```
 num   orig   new   match
 1      p      p      T
 2      t      g      F
 3      p      b      F
 4      d      d      T
 5      g      g      T
```

I want to create a new column called 'final', and if 'match' is true, I want to copy the value from orig into it. If 'match' is false, I want to copy the value from 'new' into it. Should be easy!

I use the code:

```
 data <- data %>% mutate(final = ifelse(match == T, orig, new))
```

When I run this, everything in column 'final' turns numeric.

I've also tried if_else, which generates the message "In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(13L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 4L,  :  invalid factor level, NA generated" and turns most of my FALSE values to NAs.

Comment: What if you try `ifelse(match, as.character(origin), as.character(new))`? Seems it is `factor` and `levels` are written to `final`.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: Perfect. I guess you don't want them to be factors since you didn't expect that behaviour. In that case you might want to check whether you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`when reading data for example from CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly cast the column to be character.

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
data = read.table(header = T,
text = 'num   orig   new   match
1      p      p      T
2      t      g      F
3      p      b      F
4      d      d      T
5      g      g      T')

data <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(final = as.character(ifelse(match == T, orig, new)))

str(data)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  5 variables:
#$ num  : int  1 2 3 4 5
#$ orig : chr  "p" "t" "p" "d" ...
#$ new  : chr  "p" "g" "b" "d" ...
#$ match: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#$ final: chr  "p" "g" "b" "d" ...
```

Comment: Notice that your results are quoted numbers, where OP is probably hoping for `"p", "g", "d"`.... Instead, convert the inputs to character: `ifelse(match == T, as.character(orig), as.character(new))` as Tino suggested in comments.

Comment: Fair enough - I made a quick edit to change factors to characters

Comment: @Gregor - you're absolutely correct - it's been a long day